# Styling CSS of jQuery widget divs

Tags: jquery, css

I understand I can use jQuery to style my own divs, i.e.

`$('#accordian').css({"background-color":"red"});`

But when I want to style an internal part of a widget, is there somewhere in jQuery I should be doing this or should I just create class properties in my own CSS? i.e.

```
.ui-accordion-header {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I definitely recommend using style classes in your CSS, rather than modifying via jQuery.
If you need to programatically modify, then consider simply adding or removing classes with jQuery.  This will decouple the UI handling code from the actual display.

But, in answer to your question:

```js
$("#accordion").find(".ui-accordion-header").css({"background-color":"red"})
```